# What is the reason for memsetting initialized buffer

Tags: c, initialization, memset

While traversing Wikipedia following some links, I stumbled across [the following code example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gets%28%29#Example) that initializes a char buffer to 0, but then `memset`s it to 0 before use. Is this necessary? If so, why? The reason I ask is that I am no expert, and the example clearly states that this was the coder's intention with the comment "`/* Really initialized to zeroes */`" on the `memset`, as opposed to "`/* initialized to zeroes */`" on the initialization.

EDIT: Note, I've rolled back the edit on the wikipedia page that caused this, so it is no longer visible in the link.

Comment: essencially, clean "garbage" stored for previous computations in those parts of memory allocated

Comment: You see examples in both directions - code that doesn't properly ensure a buffer is initialized, but doesn't run into problem due to some form of luck (I'd call it bad luck that testing didn't suss out the bug). On the other hand I often enough see code like: `memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));snprintf(buffer,sizeof(buffer),"foo is %d",foo);` where clearing the buffer isn't necessary since it'll always get a well-formed, null terminated string. But better safe than sorry, I guess.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
char buffer[5] = {0};  /* initialized to zeroes */

/* some declaration / statements, but no access to buffer object */

memset ( buffer, 0, sizeof buffer); /* Really initialized to zeroes */
```

in the above code, the call to `memset` is totally useless. `buffer` is already guaranteed to be initialized to `0`.

Comment: excellent, thank you. Another reason not to blindly trust Wikipedia, I suppose

Comment: I don't see any way there can be any difference between initialization with `{ 0 }` and initialization with `memset()` for a `char` array, but, for other types, there can be one on exotic systems where 0.0 is not represented with all bits zero, the null pointer one gets by writing `0` in a pointer context is not represented with all bits zero, …

Comment: @PascalCuoq, for `struct` types, `memset` would also guarantee that padding is zeroed out.

Comment: C11 also guarantees padding is zero-filled, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on ouah's answer. If you have

```
char buffer[5] = { 0 } ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    memset ( buffer, 0, sizeof buffer);
    ...
```

There might be one exception: If you **really** do low level C programming (without an operating system) and your C program is called directly without a fully working environment, then the `buffer` array might not be initialized correctly in this case, because the necessary initialization code (the code running before `main`) is missing.

In this case it's the other way round: The initialization is useless (because it does not work in this particular environment) and the `memset` is necessary.

But as I said: This really only happens with extreme low level C programming and is actually a bug in the environment, which gives you a non-C conforming environment.

Comment: thank you for this insight - though I was aware of non-standard-conforming C environments, I didn't realize there existed some that would fail to do what was explicitly asked.

Comment: I think this answer is bordering on harmful FUD. A decade or so ago, everybody held all kinds of unsubstantiated beliefs about how widely C implementations could vary, and you'd regularly find hacks to be "portable" to implementations that either never existed to begin with or were long-since obsolete, and which would not have been C implementations (but rather an ugly C-like language) even if they did exist. Bringing back this kind of doubt is **not** progress. Unless you're aware of *specific* interesting targets that don't properly initialize objects, speculation like this is not helpful.

Comment: @R.. Well: If you ever need to write parts of a boot loader in C (like I had to not too long ago), you REALLY should know what I wrote above. It's certainly **not** FUD, if you have to write on that low level you usually write your own linker scripts and that in turn might mean you simply do not have any "standard" initialization code...

Comment: The code in question has nothing to do with program initialization. The array in the question has automatic storage duration, and as such, the compiler is responsible for generating code that zero-fills it on every invocation of the function.

Comment: Ok I get it: I did not see the mentioned code in which the `buffer[5] = {0}` is actually inside a function. I just saw the first answer and assumed that the code is outside a function, which is to what my answer was referring to. I will edit this...